# android studio. Error: The file name must end with .xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to add icons on the action bar of my app, so I have imported an icon(.png) in the drawable folder but there is an error saying that the file name must end with .xml

The following is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
        android:title="@string/action_create_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

The error is coming for the first item(ic_action_name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `vector` instead `image` on `drawble folder`

Try the sample as follow on your `drawable/ic_menu_camera.xml`:

**ic_menu_camera.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-3.2,0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,6.4 0a3.2,3.2 0,1 1,-6.4 0" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M9,2L7.17,4H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v12c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V6c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-3.17L15,2H9zm3,15c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5z" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things for the error.

1. Check the place where it is showing error and see if you have any files which does not have .xml as extension and then press Shift+F6 (on Windows) to rename and add .xml
2. If you don't see any files not having .xml extension then just go to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know if this is a legitimate solution, but the fix worked for me)

---

For some reason I created a directory for images inside my res folder, `/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/appName/app/src/main/res/myImages`, with an image file (`randomimage.jpg`) that I added it as a resource to my Android project and this caused me to get the error `The file name must end with .xml`

Once I moved this image directory out of res and into `../../../../../appName`, the app built with no error. (I didn't even have to remove the resource in my Android project, just moving the real directory in Finder out of res worked.)
Hope this helps!

---

(I'm on a Mac running Monterey version 12.7.2 if that matters.)